# (OCR ) How to Recognise Handwritten fractional numbers using Neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, ocr

I want to be able to recognise handwritten math numbers using images of the numbers , i was able to do  create a ANN model for recognising simple decimal numbers , but i have no idea on how to recognise fractional number. 
What kind of ML model do i need to recognise fractional numbers (p/q forms). As i am relatively new to machine learning, i have no idea how to do it. Any study material will be appreciated.

Comment: After a weeks or so, if you do not think you get the answer you wanted, you may flag your question to request migration to [Cross Validated stack exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which might be a better place to ask OCR/ANN related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Usually one of the steps is "segmentation", where we separate the image into smaller images, one for each character/symbol.  Thus the fraction "1/13" would have four character, "1", "/", "1", and "3".  Then, you apply a neural network separately to each of those four smaller images.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition for an introduction.  OCR is covered in many standard sources.  I suggest reading the literature on the subject to learn more about standard methods.

Comment: I am not asking about  linearly written expression like 2/3+5, i want some thing in this format https://goo.gl/images/MRyYtn

Comment: @rov.er, everything I wrote still applies.  You'll need to analyze the layout and do something useful with it.

Comment: Sorry, but since i am new to ML I dint quite understand. Can you please elaborate in a little detail, how can i recognise a expression like (2 + (3/4) +1)/7 , i know how a single linear expression will be recognised, but how something like https://goo.gl/images/QQxVzD,

Comment: See specifically the "Pre-processing" section of the article.